# How to transform body of post in a querystring

Tags: php, curl, post, get, request

I have a request to do in a API and i cant make a request using body in method GET. But, as there no way to make this, the only way that i find to make is transforming a post body in a querystring and put in url.

I read some questions here, and the only way that i find to make this.

If have another way, pls tell me.

This is the body that i need transform in querystring:
`{"start":{"from":1609815601000,"to":-1}, "contentToRetrieve":["sdes"]}`

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
$data = array(
    '{"start":{"from":' => '1609815601000',
     '"to":' => '-1}',
     '"contentToRetrieve":' => '["sdes"]}'
    );

#Transformando payloadBody in questystring:
    $dataformated = http_build_query($data);
```

Response: $data

```
= Array
(
    [{"start":{"from":] => 1609815601000
    ["to":] => -1}
    ["contentToRetrieve":] => ["sdes"]}
)
```

Response $dataformate: `%7B%22start%22%3A%7B%22from%22%3A=1609815601000&%22to%22%3A=-1%7D&%22contentToRetrieve%22%3A=%5B%22sdes%22%5D%7D`